# sails.js Waterline save, read, parse lists or arrays

Tags: arrays, node.js, sails.js, waterline

**What is the correct way of creating, reading and parsing lists in Sails Waterline?**

*I haven't been able to find anything on Stack Overflow or the Waterline Github.*

To be precise I want to save a list of tags in an idea model, and then be able to search by tag.

Idea model:

```
attributes: {
  tags: {
    type: 'string'
  }
}
```

Create function (tags are passed as a string separated by commas)

```
create: function (req, res, next) {
  tags: req.param('tags').split(',');

  Idea.create(tags, function ideaCreate(err,idea) {
        //do stuff after create
    });
},
```

This succesfully stores tags: ie `tags = ['tag1', 'tag2', ..., 'tagN']

I have tried funky combinations of `.find` `.where` but to no avail.

**Easy version: How can I return the ideas that have some user requested `tagX`**

**Harder version: How can I return any ideas that have at least one tag from a list of tags?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Option one

I suggest you **create a model** for your *tags*

```
attributes: {
  ideas: {
    collection: 'idea'
  },

  name: {
    type: 'string'
  }
}
```

Next, edit your *Idea* model to refer to your *Tag* model

```
attributes: {
  tags: {
    collection: 'tag'
  },

  name: {
    type: 'string'
  }
}
```

Then to get all the ideas associated with "tagX" you'd do:

```
var tag = "tagX";
// This same code should also work with an array,
// but then you will have to use find instead of findOne
// var tag = ["tagX", "tagY", "tagZ"]

Tag.findOne({name: tag}).populate('ideas').then(function (tag) {
  // Do anything you want with the Ideas.
  tag.ideas.forEach(function(idea) {
    console.log(idea);
  });
}).catch(console.err);
```

Create Idea 'Some Grand Idea' with tags 'tagX' and 'tagY'
Adding and removing tags to/from a collection is very easy.

```
Promise.all([Idea.create({ name: 'Some Grand Idea'}),
  Tag.create({ name: 'TagX'}),
  Tag.create({ name: 'TagY'})]).
    spread(function (idea, tagX, tagY) {
      // Add tagX
      idea.tags.add(tagX.id);
      // Add tagY
      idea.tags.add(tagY.id);
      // To remove a tag, simply call remove
      // idea.tags.remove(1)
      idea.save(console.log);
    }).catch(console.log);
```

So in summary, get an Idea model. and add/remove Tag models to/from the Idea.tags collection.
This works both ways, i.e. you can get a Tag model and add an idea to the Tag.ideas collection `tag.ideas.add(someIdea.id)` and it works the same.

## Option two

Alternatively, to use the Idea model in the way you've set it up.

Get ideas with some tag:

```
Idea.find({ tags: { 'like': '%tagX%' }})
```

Get ideas with a list of tags:

```
Idea.find({
  or : [
    { tags: { 'like': '%\'tagX\'%' } },
    { tags: { 'like': '%\'tagY\'%' } },
    { tags: { 'like': '%\'tagZ\'%' } }
  ]
})
```

Comment: Firstly, why must there be a tags model? Surely I don't have to create a model every time I want to store a list. This seems unsustainable with many lists. Secondly, how do I assign tags to an idea on `create()` `update() `. Lastly, why do you store ideas within the tag model. It seems like you're storing twice as much information as needed to complete the task. Thanks,

Comment: Unless I am interpreting the question wrong, I think it makes a lot of sense to have a tag model. A tag is its own entity is it not? You want to search for tags, which sounds like you should have a model for that. If I am wrong, you could just do something like: `Idea.find({ tags: { 'like': '%tagX%' }})`
I store a _reference_ to an idea in the tag model, and a _reference_ to a tag in the idea model so you can have a many-to-many relationship between tags and ideas.

Comment: There may be a slight misinterpretation of tags. I'm using tags as `keywords` that describe an `idea`, thus I envisioned the tags being a property of each idea. My temporary work around was `Idea.find({tags: {'contains': tag}})`. However I feel like this could be parsing a string and not a list. For that project it was passable but I would never want to do that for production quality apps.

Comment: If you could add how to properly store a list in a model, save a list to that model, read from that list and also append to that list to your answer. I'll gladly accept your answer, and please leave your initial solution as a possible variation. I'll definitely use it in the new future.

Comment: I added more examples to the answer. I hope this answers your question.